# How to overcome loading chunk failed with Angular lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, webpack, code-splitting

If I make changes to my angular app the chunk names will change on build and the old version will be removed from the dist folder. Once deployed, if a user is currently on the site, and then navigates to another part of the site, I get a "loading chunk failed" error because the old file is no longer there.

My app is built using Angular CLI and is packaged using webpack.

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Comment: Angular now supports service workers so you can use those to notify the user that a new version of the app is available to download.

Comment: I have thought of that but my concern with that method is it's something people are not very familiar with on the web and they might find it a bit strange. My site is an ecommerce site and I don't want to be putting them off.

Comment: I agree that for such a public type of app you don't want to do that. I'm not sure what is a good solution then, sorry.

Comment: @dottodot did you mange to solve this?
I Have the exect same issue with react,

Comment: @tubu13 Unfortunately not, I even tried using cloudfront to cache the files for a couple of weeks in the hope it would make them available after an update, but this is clearly not the issue as I'm still getting the error on the odd occasion and not been able to determine why.

Comment: Do you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: This is one solution to the problem I found. https://medium.com/@kamrankhatti/angular-lazy-routes-loading-chunk-failed-42b16c22a377

Comment: Adding to @rmcsharry's comment, yes service workers solve the issue pretty elegantly. Service worker allows you to identify that the new app bundle was deployed. Then you have multiple options. Some are, 1) notify user regarding a new version and provide a Refresh button; 2) force app refresh on a nearest successful navigation event, in this case you're sure user don't loose any form data (of course, it depends on your app implementation) and no user action is needed

Answer (score 53):

**UPDATED SOLUTION BELOW**
*Preferred solution is converting to PWA*

---

I had the same problem and found a pretty neat solution that is not mentioned in the other answers.

You use global error handling and force app to reload if chunks failed.

```js
import {ErrorHandler, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  
  handleError(error: any): void {
   const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk [\d]+ failed/;

    if (chunkFailedMessage.test(error.message)) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

It is a simple solution and [here (Angular Lazy Routes & loading chunk failed)](https://medium.com/@kamrankhatti/angular-lazy-routes-loading-chunk-failed-42b16c22a377) is the article I got it from.

---

**EDIT: Convert to PWA**

Another solution can be to convert your Angular site to a [PWA](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started) (Progressive Web App). What this does is add a service worker that can cache all your chunks. Every time the website is updated a new manifest file is loaded from the backend, if there are newer files, the service worker will fetch all the new chunks and notify the user of the update.

[Here](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/turn-your-angular-app-into-a-pwa-in-4-easy-steps-543510a9b626) is a tutorial on how to convert your current Angular website to a PWA. Notifying the user of new updates is as simple as:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SwUpdate } from '@angular/service-worker';

@Injectable()
export class PwaService {
  constructor(private swUpdate: SwUpdate) {
    swUpdate.available.subscribe(event => {
      if (askUserToUpdate()) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Neat idea to catch the error!
It seems this would risk causing a reload loop if the chunk load failure persists?

Comment: @MychalHackman I don't think it is a problem. If you are trying to navigate to a chunk that is not present on the server, the reload will land you on the last successful loaded chunk. I have tested this myself by renaming chunks and forcing the error.

Comment: this answer is incomplete, reloading the page won't force-refresh the browser cache so this will only work for some browsers. You should clear the cache first using something like `await Promise.all((await caches.keys()).map(caches.delete))`

Comment: @Guillaume It is not necessary to refresh the cache because of hashing of the chunks. When you reload there will be a new main.XXXX.js with reference to all the new hashed bundles.

Comment: This happened to me but was due to a timeout. In that case couldn't this cause an infinite loop unless you prompt the user to reload?

Comment: Infinite-reload-loop may also happen e.g if `mixpanel.chunk.*` cannot be loaded because of AdBlocker

Comment: You could always add a reload=true boolean to the requested URL, (or reload=timestamp) making the URL unique for the browser, and then if it's in the URL do not do another reload.

Comment: I don't recommend this. reasons: 1. There might be a problem in loading a chunk. so it'll result in infinite refreshing. 2. Cache issues. So I recommend displaying an alert asking the user to refresh the page

Comment: @Vahid I updated my question to add the PWA solution which will avoid any issues.

Comment: I modified the regexp to /Loading chunk [^\s]+ failed/ because the name of my chunk was not just numbers.

Comment: @TetsutoYabuki thanks! this worked, it seems the error message changed at some point in time and the accepted answer's regexp is no longer working

Comment: @adriancho5692 I would suggest using the PWA solution instead.

Comment: How to fix this chunk load issue for chunks that still aren't loading even after refreshing the page???

Answer (score 10):

You can use custom `GlobalErrorHandler` in your application, All it does is just check the error message if it has a Loading chunk [XX] failed, and forces the app to reload and load the new fresh chunks.

Create `globalErrorHandler` with the following code

```js
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any): void {
        const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk [\d]+ failed/;
        if (chunkFailedMessage.test(error.message)) {
            if (confirm("New version available. Load New Version?")) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After creating `globalErrorHandler.ts`, you should define the `ErrorHandler` in `app.module.ts`

```js
@NgModule({
  providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler}]
})
```

Comment: The code works fine, but facing issues while writing unit tests for the service added. if window.onbeforeunload = jasmine.createSpy(); is used in the beforeeach block, the unit tests run in loop and are never finished. If window.onbeforeunload = jasmine.createSpy(); is not used then the tests fail mentioning "Some of your tests load the entire page". Can someone please help?

Comment: Just remember to add `console.error(error);` after the first `if` otherwise you lose ALL error messages in the console.

Answer (score 5):

I keep my old chunks in place for a couple days after an update for just this purpose. My app also consists of mini-SPAs, so as they move around, they're likely to pick up the new version during a page load.

Comment: This is not ideal if you need to fix something urgently in a chunk.

Answer (score 4):

If the Angular application is in an **unrecoverable** state, [the Angular docs suggestion](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-communications#handling-an-unrecoverable-state) is to subscribe to the Service Worker's `unrecoverable` updates/events then handle by what makes sense to your app.

e.g. reload the page, or notify the user, etc:

```js
@Injectable()
export class HandleUnrecoverableStateService {
  constructor(updates: SwUpdate) {
    updates.unrecoverable.subscribe(event => {
      notifyUser(
        'An error occurred that we cannot recover from:\n' +
        event.reason +
        '\n\nPlease reload the page.'
      );
    });
  }
}
```

i.e. the current version of the user's app has a reference to a file not in the cache **and** not accessible from the web server, which is typically what happens in this Chunk Load error scenario.

Answer (score 3):

In general, these errors happen during navigation (at least the way my app works). So I handle them like this:

```
router.events
    .pipe(
        filter(evt => evt instanceof NavigationError),
        map(evt => evt as NavigationError)
    )
    .subscribe(evt => {
        if (evt.error instanceof Error && evt.error.name == 'ChunkLoadError') {
            window.location.assign(evt.url);
        }
    });
```

This has the advantage of seamlessly loading the desired route.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to the game on this questions, but I would recommend changing your deployment approach.

Check out https://immutablewebapps.org/. The basic philosophy is to isolate you build time assets from your runtime variables.  This provides a bunch of benefits, but the biggest are:

- No caching problems for assets because they are isolated at the route level
- The same code that was vetted in development is used in production
- Instant fallback with hot cache for consumers in the case of a problem
- Chunks that are created are maintained for previous version isolated by routes avoiding the active deployment vs active user problem

This also should not interfere with the ** PreloadAllModules** suggestion offered by @dottodot below.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "isolate you build time assets from your runtime variables", I don't understand how to start applying this on my app.

Comment: Seems that the .org linked in this answer at time of writing is now a link farm. possibly try https://immutablewebapps.com/ instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use service workers to detect the change with "polling/intervals" and inform the user for an app update.

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started

The service worker can detect every 1minutes for example if there are new "assets/your app" and do a slide up to inform the user to reload the page or even force it if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Good Morning! I had the same problem when assembling the application using angular 11. To solve it, just run as follows.

"**ng build --named-chunks**"

Comment: This leads to caching problems on the clients browser. As the names of newly deployed JS-files aren't change anymore, the browser will still use the old (cached) files.

Comment: Not if you set the files to not be cached on the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** use `npm run ...` to serve your app, not `ng serve ...`

I was getting this error ...

[image: screenshot of error]

```
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk default-projects_app3-orders_src_app_order_order_component_ts failed.
(error: http://localhost:4205/default-projects_app3-orders_src_app_order_order_component_ts.js)
__webpack_require__.f.j@http://localhost:4205/remoteOrders.js:50599:29
```

... while going through a [module federation worked example](https://www.bitovi.com/blog/how-to-build-a-micro-frontend-architecture-with-angular).  Turned out I wasn't serving the various bits correctly.  I had read the scripts section of package.json...

```
  "scripts": {
...
    "start:app1": "ng serve",
    "start:app2": "ng serve app2-restaurant",
    "start:app3": "ng serve app3-orders",
...
  }
```

... and wrongly assumed I could just run `ng serve`, etc. at the command line.

Once my colleague pointed out I should instead run `npm run start:app1`, etc., it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the pattern: `const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk [\d]+ failed/;` wasn't working for me. I had to change it to: `const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk .*failed.*[.js\\)]/;`

Below the full ErrorHandler for Angular 17+:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    handleError(error: any): void {
        const chunkFailedMessage = /Loading chunk .*failed.*[.js\\)]/;
        if (chunkFailedMessage.test(error.message)) {
            if (confirm("New version available. Load New Version?")) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The way I use it is as follows: so for example you have multiple tabs open of your application and in one of them you logout. In my case this meant the token was expired or invalidated (SSO). So the other tab wasn't aware of this, but because the modules were lazy-loaded and you need a valid token for that, to load modules as you go, I got this: `Loading Chunk .... failed ... .js` message. In the application a notification is showed and user is sent to the login page.

Answer (score -1):

You can send some event from server side to reload the application. Also there is option to pre fetch the lazy modules in background so as to prefetch them as soon as possible instead of waiting for the request of that modules.

Comment: Actually I think using PreloadAllModules is the key as this means they get cached in the browser so it then doesn't matter if there's been a change uploaded as they will still have access to the cached version.

Comment: preloading all modules is a bad idea if speed matters to your users and you have a big SPA. One of the benefits of chunking is that parts of it can be fetched as and when they are needed, which speeds up the loading time of applications.

Answer (score -1):

Use Pre-Loading. You get the benefits of lazy loading, without the hassle it causes in situations like this. All of the chunks will be given to the user as fast as possible without slowing down the initial load time. Below is an excerpt from https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-preloading-modules-ba3c75e424cb to explain how it works (see the article for diagrams):

> First, we load the initial bundle, which contains only the components
>   we have to have to bootstrap our application. So it is as fast as it
>   can be.
>
> Then, we bootstrap the application using this small bundle.
>
> At this point the application is running, so the user can start
>   interacting with it. While she is doing it, we, in the background,
>   preload other modules.
>
> Finally, when she clicks on a link going to a lazy-loadable module,
>   the navigation is instant.
>
> We got the best of both worlds: the initial load time is as small as
>   it can be, and subsequent navigations are instant.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -11):

Clear Browser cache. Worked for me

Comment: A "normal" website user would never clear his browser cache.