# Is LazyLoading broken in Angular ? ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk xxx failed

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular15

Having the following in the `app-routing.module.ts` of my Angular 15 application:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthorizationGuard } from './core/authorization/authorization.guard';
import { LoginComponent } from './core/authorization/login/login.component';
import { RolesGuard } from './core/authorization/roles.guard';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProjectModule } from './project/project.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'projects',
    loadChildren: () => ProjectModule, //  import('./project/project.module').then(m => m.ProjectModule)
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
    canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard, RolesGuard],
    data: { roles: ['admin', 'admin-dsn'] }
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'error/:status', component: ErrorComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/404' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

If I understand well, the commented code activated the lazy loading. When using the commented code I had the follwing error:

> app-routing.module.ts:18 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk Client_app_project_project_module_ts failed. (missing: http://localhost:4200/Client_app_project_project_module_ts.js) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk Client_app_project_project_module_ts failed. (missing: http://localhost:4200/Client_app_project_project_module_ts.js) at webpack_require.f.j (jsonp chunk loading:27:1) at ensure chunk:6:1

searching similar issues on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49198268/961631) I see that the proposed solution is to reload the page when such errors arrives...

I am not sure if hardly reloading the page when arbitrary errors like this are caught is a really good idea. Could someone explain what for is that "lazy loading", is it broken in Angular and if yes should it be fixed or it's a normal behavior?

PS.

If I restore the

```
loadChildren: () => import('./project/project.module').then(m => m.ProjectModule),
```

and comment out all the `project.competent` code leaving only the declaration in .ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectComponent {}
```

and reduce the `project.component.html` to `<p>project component</p>` still get the same Chunk error.

Comment: Do you also get the error when commenting out the html and ts code in the `ProjectPage`? (Don't forget to restore the `import(...).then(m => m.ProjectModule)`)...

Comment: @Pieterjan updated the OP ro answer you question (I suppose by ProjectPage you mean project.component)