# Angular: Lazy loading without router and Chunk errors

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have written a plugin for Wordpress in Angular 16. Its a simple calendar and for the backend it should use a config interface. This interface should be loaded if a certain data attribute is set. Since I do NOT use routing (just two components) I used the following approach:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<app-calendar><ng-template #configComponent />',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  useConfigInterface: boolean = true; // for testing purpose simplified!
  @ViewChild('configComponent', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  configComponent!: ViewContainerRef;

  async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    if (this.useConfigInterface) {
      console.log('loading configSettings');
      const { CalConfigComponent } = await import(
        './calender-config/cal-config/cal-config.component'
      );
      this.configComponent.clear();
      this.configComponent.createComponent(CalConfigComponent);
    }
  }
```

The lazy loading of the component seems to work. Up to the point when I start to deploy the application. As soon as I start the deploy the app I get

`Loading chunk 42 failed`

- I tried to reload the project with [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66582020/325868) but this just
  loads the Website forever.
- Turning the existing project into a PWA
  failed (and I don't know if this would solve my problem).
- I haven't
  tried the setup with a module but would guess that I need to have
  `routing`.

Is there something I need observe for the build? e.g. some additional parameters?